Move a window to x, y posittion with GTK4
I need to position a window to a specific (x, y) position which by the way is where the mouse cursor is.
With GTK3, there is a function : gtk_window_move.
This function does not exist anymore with GTK4.
Is there something equivalent in GTK4? I tried to find the response in GTK4 documentation and I did not find...
I have read GT4 documentation.

There is no longer a way to do this in GTK4, all window management is done through the composer (Mutter, in the case of Gnome).
This type of operation is only possible through manipulation via the shell, generally using/writing an extension for the gnome shell.

This can be done with x11,--
#include <gdk/x11/gdkx.h>

int move(GtkWidget *win, int x, int y)
{
   Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

   Window w =gdk_x11_surface_get_xid(gtk_native_get_surface(GTK_NATIVE(win)));
   XMoveWindow(display, w, x, y);

   XCloseDisplay(display);
}

call it from main function----
   move(window, 200, 500);

